# Sending an MMS with a vCard attachment on Android devices

Tags: android, mms, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to find a way to send a MMS message containing a **vCard attachment**. I thought this would be a fairly easy task, but I still haven't managed to come up with something that just works over a wide variety of Android phones.

The first thing I tried was this :

**Define an intent showing a list of apps capable of sending the vCard**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/x-vcard");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"MMS with vCard");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse (someFilereference);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select MMS application."));
```

When using this, I noticed the following :

- On a **Samsung Galaxy S**, the chooser allowed me to pick Bluetooth,Gmail **and the Messaging app**. When using the Messaging app, the attachment and text was present, and I could send the MMS. I processed the MMS on an old Sony Ericson phone (pre-android) and the vCard was processed fine.
- On a **Google Nexus S** and **Motorola DroidX**, the chooser only allowed me to pick Bluetooth and Gmail. (**the Messaging app was missing from the chooser**).

(My conclusion) : It appears that Android doesn't come with a stock application that is capable of satisfying the Intent specified here. (no app allows with the text/x-vcard mimeType). The Galaxy S comes with its own Messaging app that is capable of handling the vcard mimetype.

That's all very well, but how do we go about and solve this ?

I tried the following approach :

**Launch the messaging intent directly by specifying the class**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
i.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"); 
i.setType("text/x-vcard");
i.putExtra("sms_body", "SomeText");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse (someFileRef);  
startActivity(i);
```

Using this code, the messaging app is launched directly. This approach was choosen as it at least allows us to pop a messaging app on the Nexus S (before with the chooser, the messaging app was not present).

On the **Samsung Galaxy S**, the attachment is added on the MMS compose screen and is correctly sent.
On the **Google Nexcus S**, the attachment is not present.

When removing the mimeType from the Intent, the Messaging app pops an **Unsupported media type** error message.

So the questions is : is there a simple and uniform piece of code that allows you to send an MMS with a vCard attachment ?